# Parallel run on multiple devices using Appium with Python

Tags: python-2.7, appium, selenium-grid

Please help me out how to run the single script in multiple devices in parallel using Python..?

I have started two different Appium servers using Selenium Grid.. But I'm not able to write the code to start the different drivers in two devices and run script parallel using Python..

Comment: is jafer answered your question? then you can accept as accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

Its better if you prepared a separate file for values which you are going to use it and separate code file where you can mention your test cases and the keywords.

## Here is an example for values files :

Device:
  SamsungA7:
    Device_name: 111354d3                                        #Device id
    server: http://localhost:4723/wd/hub                             #appium server URL
    appPackage:  com.android.contacts                                  #app package name of your application
    appActivity:  com.android.contacts.activities.PeopleActivity               #app activity of your application
    platfrom:  6.0                                                   #platfom version of your device
    automation:  Appium                                              #Appium is used in automationName instead of Uiautomator for deviced on android version 4.4

## Here is an example for the Code file:

*** Settings ***
Test Setup       Sum of two numbers a+b
Test Teardown    Set the Default Values 
Suite setup      Set value

*** Variables ***
  Default Values 
    Value of A    1
    Value of B    1

*** Test Cases ***

```
[Setup]  Sum of first two numbers should be 6
Enter first value    5
Enter second value   1
5+1
```

*** Test Cases ***

```
[Setup] Sum of Second two numbers should be 11
Enter sum of first value   6
Enter second value    5
6+5
```

*** Keywords ***
    Test TearDown
        Set the Default values

Note: Code file should be in the .robot format and you can save the script file in yaml or notepad or json.